# Group By part of a strings

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a various date times stored as strings in my sqlserver database.

```
07/May/2012:00:01:49
07/May/2012:00:02:14
07/May/2012:00:02:26
```

This column is called datetimesent and it is quite easy to select group by on it. For example:

```
SELECT DateTimeSent, COUNT(*) FROM MyTable where group by DateTimeSent
```

This will group be every second. What I'd like to do is group by every ten seconds, so instead of grouping by the entire string, group by all of it except last letter.  How do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider the use of `datetime` instead but this will do what you want.

```
group by left(DateTimeSent, 19)
```